# TFS release management build agent is not available

Tags: tfs, release-management, build-agent

Recently I was able to configure a build agent on my laptop and queue a successful build on TFS.

Then I tried to switch to a build server VM. I created a service account with the same rights as my account I was using from the laptop and configured a new build agent on the machine to use the service account and the same pool and started the agent.

When I log into TFS I can see the agent running in the correct pool, and it is green. So I disabled the agent from the laptop, so it would use the new agent on the build server. However, when I queue a build to the pool, the message displays "all possible agents have been disabled". So my new agent is in the pool and enabled, but when I queue a build it is not seen as a possible agent.

How do I make the new agent pick up the request to queue a new build? I verified it's running as a service on the build machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the service account is a domain account and is part of “Agent Pool Service Accounts” group in TFS under your Agent Pool.

Then check the capabilities, and make sure the agent capabilities match the one set in the build definition. In addition, private agents give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. You can compare with you laptop, to check if there are any necessary dependent software misinstalled.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I found the problem yesterday. I needed the full Visual Studio install on my build machine. Just the build agent and the .Net frameworks were not enough.

Comment: After I installed Visual Studio, and other software, I had to remove/reconfigure the agent to get TFS/VSTS to pick up on the new capabilities